# portable system/process information library

Tags: c++, operating-system, system, memory-management, cpu-usage

I need to retrieve process information in a C/C++ program. I need at least basic things like CPU% and memory usage, but additional details would be useful as well.

The problem is that I need to use this information in a portable program, that will run on multiple platforms: windows, linux, MAC and possibly Solaris too.

Is there a library that I can use or do I need to write my own HAL for the different platforms? I tried to look on google, but I couldn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with a complete solution, but here's a link to my CPULoadMeter class, which you can use to poll CPU usage information over time.  It works under MacOS/X, Windows, and Linux (and possibly other Unixy-OS's that have /proc/stat also, I don't know).  Perhaps you can use it as a starting point.

https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/util/CPULoadMeter.h
https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/util/CPULoadMeter.cpp

Answer (score 0):

This information must be retrieved from the OS.
By definition this is non portable, but there are a couple of OS abstraction layers out there. The one that springs to mind is [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html).

Comment: ACE doesn't seem to contain what OP asked for. Qt, btw, doesn't, either. Seems to be non-trivial...

Comment: The problem is trivial. It is just that each system is different.